# Why SVG filters does not apply to HTML element in my code?

Tags: html, css, svg, filter

I have created a nice svg frame by applying filters in Inkscape v 0.91. 
I want to apply it to an HTML element too. However I cant. I was expecting that the div element turns into a frame like rect element of svg. Can you explain to me why svg filters did not apply to div element. Many people seem to be able to apply svg filters to html elements.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    filter: url(#aslan);
">Duh ! Its not working </div>

<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="297mm" width="210mm" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047">


    <defs>
        <filter id="aslan" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" result="result1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feBlend result="result5" mode="normal" in2="result1" in="SourceGraphic"></feBlend>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="result6" in="result5"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feComposite operator="xor" result="result8" in2="result6" in="result6"></feComposite>
            <feComposite operator="in" result="fbSourceGraphic" in2="result8" in="result6"></feComposite>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 1 0 " result="fbSourceGraphicAlpha" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" result="result0" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feSpecularLighting lighting-color="rgb(255,255,255)" specularConstant="2" result="result1" specularExponent="55" in="result0" surfaceScale="2">
                <fePointLight y="-10000" x="-5000" z="20000"></fePointLight>
            </feSpecularLighting>
            <feComposite in2="fbSourceGraphicAlpha" k1="1" result="result2" in="result1" operator="arithmetic"></feComposite>
            <feComposite in2="result2" k3="1" k2="0.5" result="result4" in="fbSourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic"></feComposite>
            <feComposite operator="over" result="result91" in2="result4" in="result9"></feComposite>
            <feBlend result="fbSourceGraphic" mode="screen" in2="result91"></feBlend>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 1 0" result="fbSourceGraphicAlpha" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix>
            <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" in="fbSourceGraphic" flood-opacity=".49804"></feFlood>
            <feComposite operator="in" result="composite1" in2="fbSourceGraphic" in="flood"></feComposite>
            <feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="3.6" in="composite1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset result="offset" dx="-12.2396" dy="6"></feOffset>
            <feComposite operator="over" result="fbSourceGraphic" in2="offset" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feComposite>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 1 0" result="fbSourceGraphicAlpha" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix>
            <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" in="fbSourceGraphic" flood-opacity=".49804"></feFlood>
            <feComposite operator="in" result="composite1" in2="fbSourceGraphic" in="flood"></feComposite>
            <feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="3.6" in="composite1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset result="offset" dx="-12.2" dy="6"></feOffset>
            <feComposite operator="over" result="fbSourceGraphic" in2="offset" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feComposite>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 1 0" result="fbSourceGraphicAlpha" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix>
            <feConvolveMatrix divisor="1" kernelMatrix="0 -0.15 0 -0.15 1.6 -0.15 0 -0.15 0" targetY="1" order="3 3" targetX="1" in="fbSourceGraphic"></feConvolveMatrix>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect transform="matrix(.59683 0 0 .59683 72.863 46.68)" height="115.16" filter="url(#aslan)" width="220.21" y="127.3" x="202.74" fill="#0f0"></rect>
</svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have figured out that it is related to CSS engine of browser and I should use -webkit-filter: instead of just filter: . 
I wont delete the question tho, for people who have similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add 
-webkit-filter: url(#aslan);
to your style definition. So the final style definition should be like this:

```
<div style="
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    filter: url(#aslan);
    -webkit-filter: url(#aslan);
">Duh ! Its not working </div>
```